Issue with Obtaining NetworkId in Test Class for Community User
I'm facing a problem while attempting to retrieve the networkId in my test class for a functionality that involves fetching a user's photo in a community context. In my method, I'm using Network.getNetworkId() to obtain the networkId, and then utilizing it to fetch the user's photo via ConnectApi.UserProfiles.getPhoto(networkId, userId). However, during the test class execution, the networkId is returning as null.
Despite referencing a StackExchange post for insights and ensuring the necessary permissions, the networkId is still coming up as null in the test class.
Could someone can provide insights on why the networkId might be returning null in the test class despite functioning correctly within the method? I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions or guidance on resolving this issue. Thank you!

As the referenced Q&A shows you, querying NetworkMember will work. Network.getNetworkId() returns null in a test context regardless of permissions or how you execute it.

Essentially, a community user can be a member of many different digital experiences and the network ID will vary at runtime depending on the experience the user is interacting with. In a test there is no current digital experience so you get null, and always will in tests.

What exactly are you trying to test and do you need to specifically test it? Showing the code and unit test can help us understand.

Yes, we need to query the NetworkMember and that will serve the purpose.

In actual logic need to replace Network.getNetworkId() with SOQL.
UserRole userRole_1 = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE DeveloperName = 'YourUserRole' LIMIT 1];
    Profile profile_1 = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Customer Community Login User' LIMIT 1];
    User admin = [SELECT Id, Username, UserRoleId FROM User WHERE Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' AND UserRoleId = :userRole_1.Id LIMIT 1];
    User user_1;
    System.runAs(admin) {
      Account account_1 = new Account( Name = 'Community'  );
      insert account_1;
      
      Contact contact_1 = new Contact(AccountId = account_1.Id, LastName = 'xgeek');
      insert contact_1;
      
      user_1 = new User( 
        Email = 'yourusername@gmail.com',
        ProfileId = profile_1.Id, 
        UserName = 'yourusername@gmail.com', 
        Alias = 'Test',
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York',
        EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',
        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
        ContactId = contact_1.Id,
        PortalRole = 'Manager',
        FirstName = 'Firstname',
        LastName = 'Lastname'
      );
      insert user_1;
    }
    Test.startTest();
    System.runAs(user_1) {
      System.assertEquals(UserInfo.getUserId(), user_1.Id);
    System.debug([ select NetworkId from NetworkMember where MemberId = :admin.Id order by Id desc limit 1 ]);
      // your test code for Salesforce Community
    }
    Test.stopTest();

